# Argument of function is a property that exists in a type of Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to write a function that returns a single property that exists on a type:

```
type CustomType = {
    property1: boolean;
    property2: numeric;
};

private getData(obj): CustomType {
    // do stuff
    return dataObj;
}

private getBooleanValue(obj, key): boolean {
    const value = this.getData(obj)[key];
    // do stuff
    return value;
}
```

I want to put a restriction on getBooleanValue's key, that the key is part of CustomType - for example:

```
getBooleanValue(obj, "property1") // OK
getBooleanValue(obj, "property2") // ERROR, TypeScript won't allow this
```

Comment: Why not use `key: keyof TypeB` [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oDMD22BcUAdgK4C2ARhAE5QC+AUKJLPAEIrpTkCGVBAzsCoBLQgHM69epmKEAxsGHZCUMRGAARbsG4AKbOQBWBOJAQBKE23T0odqFXXEqKjDz5QARDwBenyQzSsgpKKmrAAGrcADbEEPpGVmYANFAA1hAgBBkg2JgskKyWXLjRENyutvaOwM5h6lo6CYbmANo5ALpQAITIqLIAJhCYohAD9LRAA)?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be a [mcve] since it refers to types and values not present.  Consider editing the code so that someone can drop it into an IDE and the only issue is the one you're asking about.  Good luck!

Comment: @ford04 - yeah! You are right :) Thank You for help, I will edit the solution i made below.

Comment: @jcalz - fixed the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this kind of works, but it doesn't seem the best solution:

```
type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never;
};

type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> = FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base];


private getValue(
    obj, 
    key: keyof AllowedNames<CustomType, boolean>
): boolean {
    const value = this.getData(obj)[key];
    // do stuff
    return value;
}
```

EDIT: I've found a great article about filtering props in types (conditional types):
https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `key: AllowedNames<CustomType, boolean>` and you don't need the `SubType` or `Booleans` definitions?

Comment: @jcalz You are perfectly right :) Fixed the solution!